# Data not found in shared cluster MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a shared cluster version 3.2 but some users inserted data into replica set directly, so I cannot find that by mongos.

How to fix it?

Thanks,
Hiko

Answer (score 0):

I export and clean data and then import via mongos.